# How to access a shared drive from the command prompt on OS X

Tags: macos, shell, network-shares, finder

I have a shared drive called "music". It shows up in Finder without problems.

How do I access this from the command prompt on a Mac?  I can't find it anywhere – is there a way to access it?

Comment: Where is it physically located? Another partition? Another computer? NAS? Online library? What's the path?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If a network share is already mounted in the Finder, it will be accessible through `/Volumes` in a shell, e.g. if your share is called "music", you'll find it under:

```
/Volumes/music
```

---

If you still need to mount it, you can actually mount it wherever you like — ideally not to `/Volumes`, but for example on your desktop. You can use [**`mount_smbfs`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/mount_smbfs.8.html) to do so. The complete syntax would be like this:

```
mount_smbfs //[domain;][user[:password]@]server[/share] ~/Desktop/music
```

In your case, if you have no special login and just `guest` credentials, maybe the following is enough – when prompted for a password, you can just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and skip it:

```
mkdir -p ~/Desktop/music
mount_smbfs //host/music ~/Desktop/music
```

… and voilà:

> [image]

If you have a user and password, you could use `//user@host/music`, and then enter the password interactively.

To safely unmount it, just call the following:

```
umount ~/Desktop/music/
```

Comment: When I try this I get: mount_smbfs: server connection failed: Cannot allocate memory

Answer (score 0):

I have to test this on my Mac, but this article explains using the smbclient to execute what you need.

Take a [look over here.](http://osxdaily.com/2009/09/24/access-and-mount-an-smb-share-via-command-line/)

In a nutshell:

```
$ smbclient -U user -I 192.168.0.105 -L //smbshare/
```